# why do laravel ignition error page could never get the error line number right?

Tags: laravel

not entirely important but it's kind of a flaw of the framework.

let's say i'm working on a blade file now i'm using an arrow to get a value from an array.
definitely that would return an error of something like `using -> on a non-object`

then it shows my code below and is trying point me the line to where the error is, but every single time I see this, its always the wrong line number. why is that?

is it just a flaw? or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Did you ever find a solution for this? It works as expected in Laravel 6 & 7.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a comments line in your blade code?. laravel does not render blade page directly it creates a file in 'storage/framework/views' without comment code here you find the exact line number as you seeing in your error.

Comment: basically, it creates a compiled file, and the error line number you noticed is compiled file line error number.

Comment: it is a flaw in the framework then... since the framework should know that it is not rendering the blade file directly, so it should either show the compiled blade file so that the line number that is reported will be correct or it should find the exact line in the blade file to show the correct error.

Comment: if you want to see the correct line number of the error, In the error message mention a file alphanumeric with PHP extension there you find the exact line of error.